# Axis numbering for R's apply function

Tags: r

Given the following simple matrix

```
mymatrix<-matrix(1:9,nrow=3)
mymatrix
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Let's do column and row wise sums:

```
 apply(mymatrix,1,sum)
[1] 12 15 18
> apply(mymatrix,2,sum)
[1]  6 15 24
```

My intuition would have the axes reversed from what we see above.  I think of `rows` as the first dimension of a matrix. So applying the `sum` operation on axis-1 should give us row sums.  What is the proper way to understand the thinking of having the opposite polarity?

Comment: Probably you are coming from a python background and numpy has the reverse of apply. Note that you just described margin 1 as being rowsums. meaning take row1 sum it and that will be the first result. take row 2 sum it and that will be the second result. so in this case, row 1is 1,4,7 and summing those will give you 12, and that is why `apply(m, 1, sum)` returns the rowsums

Comment: @onyambu. `apply` does exactly what I expected, it's the `matrix` operation that is columns first (and I did not notice it): see my answer below

Comment: I get your point, but still in a way different from python. eg if you had `a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3).T; np.apply_along_axis(sum, 0, a)` will give the column sums instead of the rowsums, also `a.sum(0)` will give column sums instead of rowsums yet margin 0 implies applying the function over the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually misunderstood what  `matrix(1:9,nrow=3)` generates: I had not paid attention to the output. I had presumed it would create

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But instead it is columns-first.  So `apply` does exactly what I expect: sums rows when axis=1 and sums columns when axis=2.